# Get list of all second-order keys in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

From my dictionary of dictionaries I would like to receive a list of all second-order keys.

```
myDict = {
    u'A': {'1998': u'ATLANTA'},
    u'B': {'1999': u'MANNHEIM'},
    u'C': {'2000': u'BERLIN'},
    u'D': {'1998': u'CHICAGO', '1999': u'PRINCETON'},
    u'E': {'2000': u'LOUISIANA'},
    u'F': {'1998': u'NEW YORK', '1999': u'NEW YORK'}
}
```

I do

```
years = []
for author in author_aff_dict:
    years.extend(author_aff_dict[author].keys())
print uniqfy(years)
```

where `uniqfy()` is from http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark:

```
def uniqfy(seq, idfun=None):
   if idfun is None:
       def idfun(x): return x
   seen = {}
   result = []
   for item in seq:
       marker = idfun(item)
       if marker in seen: continue
       seen[marker] = 1
       result.append(item)
   return result
```

Everything works as expected (i.e. `years` is `['1998', '2000', '1999']`), but I am sure there must be a better/shorter way in getting a list of all keys of the nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a set comprehension :

```
>>>s= {j for i in myDict.values() for j in i}
set(['1999', '1998', '2000'])
```

Then if you just want a list object you can use `list()` to convert the `set` to list.

```
>>> list(s)
['1999', '1998', '2000']
```

Comment: I just saw this list not ordered. Is there a way to retrieve the keys in the same order they are in an OrderedDict()?

Comment: If you want to keep the  duplicated values ‘myDict.values’ will give you what you want otherwise you can sort the result of my answer with ‘sorted‘ function.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> myList = []
>>> for i in myDict.values():
...     for j in i.keys():
...             if j not in myList: myList.append(j)
...             else: continue
... 
>>> myList
['1998', '2000', '1999']
```

edit: i'd prefer @Kasra's answer :)

Comment: Good try but in this case i think the OP's approach is better ;)